# using windowTranslucentNavigation and transparent navigationBarColor puts "banded" gradient behind the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added the following to my styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

This gives an ugly banded gradient behind the navigation bar. Is there a way to make the gradient smoother? If not, is there a way to remove the gradient all together? I still want to keep the navigation bar and status bar but either transparent or non banded.

Comment: Try to remove  `item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` and stay only set colors.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using this.?

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```